# Ant Design Vue: Join addonBefore value with user input

Tags: vue.js, antd

So I have this input field with select options, so that the user doesn't have to specify what type of input he has, but the thing is, I want the `addonBefore` value as a prefix to the input. I thought that's what it will do, but it just passes my input without any prefix.

Here's the code I wrote

```html
    <a-input defaultValue="Device/Order ID" v-model="code" v-on:keyup.enter="new_scan">
        <a-select slot="addonBefore" defaultValue="device-" style="width: 90px">
          <a-select-option value="device-" prefix="device-">Device</a-select-option>
          <a-select-option value="order-" prefix="order-">Order</a-select-option>
        </a-select>
    </a-input>
```

And even with the `prefix` it's not working. Is there any way I can make it so that if `Device` is selected and the *user input* is 12345, the end input is `device-12345`?

Thanks in advance!